# Woocommerce checkout update totals with datepicker

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, woocommerce-offtopic, datepicker

I've added a new date field on the checkout page. I'd like to create a date based delivery fee calculation.

The date field has the '*update_totals_on_change*' class. When changing this manually the totals is recalculated as expected.
Unfortunately when I use the jQuery datepicker on this field the totals not updating.

In my opinion, I should trigger the *update_checkout* method in the datepicker's callback. In the WooCommerce `checkout.js` script there's a *input_changed();* which fires the *$( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );*. But I can't call them directly from the datepicker's callback.

```
jQuery("#delivery_date").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    firstDay: 1,
    onSelect: function () {
        $( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
    }
});
```

How can I get working the update_totals_on_change functionality with datepicker?

Edit:

I tried it with triggering the *change()* function but the datepicker stops working all the times when a callback function was called.

```
jQuery("#delivery_date").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    firstDay: 1,
    onSelect: function () {
        $(this).change();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the trigger in a standalone callback.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#datetimepicker" ).datetimepicker({
        onClose:function(ct,$i){
        my_callback();
        }
    });
    function my_callback() {
        jQuery( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure why wrapping the trigger in a function works, but I had the same issue as the original poster and this worked for me. It seems calling the anonymous function might be out of scope, perhaps. Sorry I don't have a better explanation.